# One question survey app Google Apps Script and Google Sheets with user management

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to do a little bit of "crowdsourcing" for my work and it would consist in a very simple web app where a user can register/log in, and then be taken to a page where a picture is shown to a user and submit a number.

I'd like to be able to set up a few rules to choose which picture the user will see (so he won't have to answer twice the same question and also to allow some overlap between users to compare their answers).

We can assume that I have a google sheet with a list of images URLs that can be accessed and that I would like the answers to be populated there.

I figured that this tutorial would be a good start since it handles user creation and management and user can submit ideas :

[Creating a CRUD Web App with Google Sheets](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2017/08/12/creating-crud-web-app-google-sheets/)

That being said I'm a bit clueless, I've tried to look for sample scripts deployed as web app but it's hard to know where to start.

I'll appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script is, basically, a javascript environment with a set of libraries that interact with the Google Apps. For instance, to read or store information from/to Google Sheets or Google Docs. If you know javascript, you can create simple applications there. In addition, you can create plugins for Google Applications if you are interested.

---

#### A very simple example

Suppose you wanna display an HTML page. You can create an stand-alone script (an script not-bound to a G suite application) and use the content or the HTML services.

You can create a function that [sends a simple message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) to the browser using the `ContentService`:

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello, world!');
}
```

Or you can create a function that [sends an HTML file in the same project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) using the `HtmlService`:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

Once you have created the function, you must [deploy the script as a web application](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

- Save the script as a new version doing **File > Manage Versions** and **Save new version**.
- Then, publish the app using **Publish > Deploy as web app** and provinding information about the permissions for the application.
- After Google publishes the application, it gives you an URL to access the application,

You may check more in a simple tutorial on [producing content with Google Apps Script](http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/). In addition, you may check the google guide to use the `HtmlService` to [provide templated content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), i.e. where the HTML are templates which data is provided by javascript functions and variables.

---

#### Getting started with Google Apps Script

To start, you may check some tutorials in the internet:

- Google has [some tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) and a [series of Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL68F511F6E3C122EB).

In addition, you may find multiple resources for Google App Scripts that may help you:

- Google has a list of [sample projects](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples)
- Tanakeich has a list of resources for [taking advantage of Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-google-apps-script).
- Oshliaer has another [list of resources](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-awesome-list).
- There are Google Codelab (tutorials) for [Apps Scripts](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Apps).  They include a lab for [using Google Sheets as a reporting tool](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sheets-api/) and for creating a [Hangouts Chat bot with Apps Script](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chat-apps-script/)

---

#### Developing Google Apps Script projects locally

Although Google Apps Script provides a web interface to create your applications (your scripts), a better idea may be to create the software locally, using more-traditional tools for Javascript.

- [Clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) is a command-line tool to develop locally Google Apps Script projects.
- Google has a codelab that teach you [how to use clasp](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I think I will be able to do some reverse engineering of the project I found and start learning from there!